# Add to cart without submit button?

Tags: expresso-store

In Store is there a tag I can use to add a product (no product options) to the cart, simply by loading the product page? That is, there is no add to cart submit button that needs clicking.

This would be the Cartthrob equivalent
http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart/index.html

Best wishes
Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in Store would be to use AJAX to POST directly to our action URL. You can simply add the standard product tag/form to your page, then use javascript to call `$("#productform").submit()`.

There isn't any way to add an item directly to the cart using a GET request, since GET requests should never be used to change the state of a system (because they could be easily triggered by malicious sites using simple hidden image tags etc).